# upload picture when register laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make a user crud. Everything works very well the user this create, but I had the problem is when I put to upload a profile image.

UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::latest()->paginate(50);



        return view('superadmin.user.index', compact('users'))

            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $usersall = User::all();
        return view('superadmin.user.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'secretword' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $input = $request->all();



        if ($image = $request->file('image')) {

            $destinationPath = 'images/';

            $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);

            $input['image'] = "$profileImage";
        }

        User::create($input);

        return redirect()->route('user.index')
            ->with('success', 'User created');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // $request->validate([

        //     'name' => 'required',

        //     'detail' => 'required'

        // ]);

  

        // $input = $request->all();

  

        // if ($image = $request->file('image')) {

        //     $destinationPath = 'images/';

        //     $profileImage = date('YmdHis') . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //     $image->move($destinationPath, $profileImage);

        //     $input['image'] = "$profileImage";

        // }else{

        //     unset($input['image']);

        // }

          

        // $users->update($input);

    

        // return redirect()->route('products.index')

        //                 ->with('success','Product updated successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $users = User::find($id);
        $users->delete();
        return redirect()->route('user.index')->with('success', 'Utilisateur supprime');
    }
}
```

view/superadmin/user/create.blade.php

```
@extends('superadmin.layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <!-- left column -->
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <!-- general form elements -->
            <div class="card card-primary">
                <div class="card-header">
                    <h3 class="card-title">New User</h3>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <!-- form start -->
                <form method="POST" action="{{ route('user.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Name</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name" name="name" required>
                        </div>
                        @error('name')
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputFile">Image</label>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div class="custom-file">
                                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="Image" name="image" required>
                                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error('image')
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Secret word</label>
                            <input id="secretword" type="text" class="form-control @error('secretword') is-invalid @enderror" name="secretword" value="{{ old('secretword') }}" required autocomplete="secretword" autofocus>
                        </div>
                        @error('secretword')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Telegram</label>
                            <input id="telegram" type="text" class="form-control @error('telegram') is-invalid @enderror" name="telegram" value="{{ old('telegram') }}" required autocomplete="telegram" autofocus>
                        </div>
                        @error('telegram')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email</label>
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                        </div>
                        @error('email')
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ $message }}</div>
                        </div>
                        @enderror

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Password') }}</label>
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div> 
                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                        

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                        </div>
            </div>

            <!-- /.card-body -->
            <div class="card-footer pt-0">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!--/.col (right) -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
</div>
@endsection
```

view/superadmin/user/index.blade.php

```
@extends('superadmin.layouts.app')
@section('stylesheets')
<style>
    .thread-parent {
        position: relative;

    }

    .thread-child {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        top: 10%;
        left: 24%;
    }

    .card-inner {
        position: relative;
    }

    .fa-window-close {
        position: absolute;
        right: 5px;
        top: 5px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .child {
        word-break: break-all;
    }
</style>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container thread-parent">
                                <a href="{{ route('user.create') }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>

    <table class="table" id="example1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Action</th>
                <th scope="col">Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Image</th>
                <th scope="col">Telegram</th>
                <th scope="col">Secret word</th>
                <th scope="col">Thread</th>
                <th scope="col">Reply thread</th>
                <th scope="col">Messages</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($users as $user)
            <tr>
                
                <td>
                    <!-- <a href="{{ route('threads.edit', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:showBlockBox({{ $user->id }})" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" style="z-index: 999"><i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i></a>
                            -->
                            <!-- <a href="{{ route('user.create', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a> -->
                            <a href="{{ route('user.destroy', $user->id) }}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this')"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
                <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                <td> <img src="/images/{{ $users->image }}" width="100px"></td>
                <td><a href=""><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a></td>
                <td>{{ $user->secretword }}</td>
                <td><a href=""><i class="fas fa-comment"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><i class="fas fa-comments"></i></a></td>
                <td><a href=""><i class="fas fa-envelope"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
@endsection
@section('scripts')
<script>
    $(function() {
        // $("#example1").DataTable({
        //     "responsive": true,
        //     "lengthChange": false,
        //     "autoWidth": false,
        //     "buttons": ["copy", "csv", "excel", "pdf", "print", "colvis"]
        // }).buttons().container().appendTo('#example1_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)');

        $('#example1').DataTable({
            "paging": true,
            "lengthChange": false,
            "searching": true,
            "ordering": true,
            "info": true,
            "autoWidth": false,
            "responsive": true,
        });
    });

    function showBlockBox(threadid) {
        $('.thread-child').show();
        $('#threadid').val(threadid);
    }

    function hideBlockBox() {
        $('.thread-child').hide();
        $('#threadid').val("");
    }
</script>
@endsection
```

model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Qirolab\Laravel\Reactions\Traits\Reacts;
use Qirolab\Laravel\Reactions\Contracts\ReactsInterface;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail, ReactsInterface
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, Reacts;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'secretword',
        'image',
        'telegram',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany(Role::class)
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this
            ->belongsToMany('App\User')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function authorizeRoles($roles)
    {
        if ($this->hasAnyRole($roles)) {
            return true;
        }
        abort(401, 'This action is unauthorized.');
    }

    public function hasAnyRole($roles)
    {
        if (is_array($roles)) {
            foreach ($roles as $role) {
                if ($this->hasRole($role)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if ($this->hasRole($roles)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function hasRole($role)
    {
        if ($this->roles()->where('name', $role)->first()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

The user crud was working very well until I tried to upload the images, in the phpmyadmin it tells me that the image was uploaded but no image was saved in the public file or storage I think I have a controller error but I don't know where. And when I try to display the image of the user it gives me this error: Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$image How can I adjust so that the user image this upload is displayed without error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UserController`, `store` method

Change this

```
$destinationPath = 'images/';
```

to

```
$destinationPath = public_path('images/');
```

Also, In `view/superadmin/user/index.blade.php`

Change this

```
<td> <img src="/images/{{ $users->image }}" width="100px"></td>
```

to

```
<td> <img src="/images/{{ $user->image }}" width="100px"></td>
```